# Publishing desktop applications to windows store

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, desktop-application, windows-store

I need to know is there any way to publish traditional desktop applications to windows store. The link,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/06/08/listing-your-desktop-app-in-the-store.aspx

says we cannot upload the desktop app, but we can give a url for the customers to download. 
I need to know, is there any way to directly upload the exe (or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft works on a tool for this aka Project Centennial which is not available for public yet. Officially from [here](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/bridges):

> Your application should already run on Windows 10. To make it easier for you to distribute and monetize your application, we are developing "Project Centennial". This toolkit will enable you to package and publish your .NET and Win32 applications to the Windows Store. "Project Centennial" is expected to be available for public testing next year.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @vzayko, Project Centennial will be the bridge to use to get your classic Windows application into the Windows Store.

However, until the Windows classic app bridge is publicly available (which should be sometime this year), there is no way to submit your application to the Windows Store.