# Creating app packages for Windows Store from existing Exe

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, windows-store-apps, desktop-application, electron

I have a HTML/JavaScript project that runs inside a NodeJS wrapper (bundled by Electron).

An .exe file is then created from the bundle, using `node-enigmavirtualbox` package, resulting in a portable Windows Desktop Application.

I am using Windows 7 myself, but the App runs on 7, 8, 8.1 and 10 (tested) and my intention is to distribute for all of these platforms.

I am now trying to submit this Application to the Windows Store, where I am required to upload my code as packages in specific formats (.xap, .appx, .appxbundle, .appxupload).

I have already an account at Windows Dev Center and reserved a name for my App.

**How can I import my .exe file into Visual Studio and generate the app packages from it that are required for Windows Store?**

I have tried extracting my .exe file and opening the contents in Visual Studio,
but the *Project > Store > Create App Packages* menu is greyed-out.

I am referring to this guide https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454036.aspx
There is supposed to be a tool called Project Centennial that takes care of this, but I haven't been able to find more info about this.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do it manually to be able to reuse the code of your existing application. Therefore create a new project in Visual Studio. Use the Javascript-->Windows-->Universal Template.
[image]

This will set up your solution. It basically is an app that is based on Javascript and HTML. You will probably be able to reuse big parts of your code by copying the files of your electron app into the structure in solution explorer but you have to do the wiring manually.

It's not possible currently to do a simple import. Project Centennial has been announced last year but is not available yet.
As you're using a HTML/JS based application and HTML/JS is a supported language for building Windows Universal Apps it will probably be possible for you to reuse big parts of your code using the approach above, but it certainly depends on the details of your app.

Comment: So basically that means porting the HTML/JS parts over and ditching the Electron code in favor of something else?
How would I implement the functionality that Electron handles right now such as native context menu, reading from file system, setting user agent, display task bar balloon tips etc.? Are there any resources / tutorials regarding this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned in the related question below but applies here, Project Centennial will be the bridge to use to get your classic Windows '.exe' applications into the Windows Store.

However, until the Windows classic app bridge is publicly available (which should be sometime this year), there is no way to submit your application to the Windows Store.

As you've created your application with HTML/JS, it would be quite easy to port your application to the Universal Windows Platform but it isn't a straight port like the Project Centennial bridge aims to solve.

Related question - [Publishing desktop applications to windows store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34717516/publishing-desktop-applications-to-windows-store/34720282#34720282)